# Flutter - Convert image to bitmap

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert an image captured by `screenshot` package to a bitmap. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

onPressed: () {
    screenshotController
        .captureAsUiImage(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 10))
        .then((capturedImage) async {
        final encoder = img.BmpEncoder();
        final encodedImg =
            encoder.encodeImage(capturedImage as img.Image);
    }).catchError((onError) {
        print(onError);
    });
},
```

It builds without errors but when I click on the button I get the following in the terminal:

```
flutter: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'Image' in type cast where
  Image is from dart:ui
  Image is from package:image/src/image.dart
```

I understand the problem, that `captureAsUiImage()` returns `ui:Image` while `encodeImage()` takes an `img:Image`. But I don't know how to cast between them.
Or if there is a better way to convert the captured image to bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing the image as Uint8List:

```
onPressed: () {
 screenshotController
    .capture()
    .then((Uint8List bytes) {
       Bitmap bitmapImg = _fromUint8List(bytes);
 }).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
 });
},

_fromUint8ListToBitmap(Uint8List bytes){
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.fromHeadful(imageWidth, imageHeight, bytes);
   return bitmap;
}
```

and change `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` with your image width and height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works partially. `Uint8List headedBitmap = bitmap.buildHeaded();` This line cause an error `Flutter: Bad State - too few elements`

Comment: I edited the code, try this new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_converter):

```
final encodedImg = capturedImage.bmpUint8List;
```

I'm the author.